# Scraping EDGAR HTML file and want to convert into dataframe

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm new to scraping the website

```
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1383094/000095013120003579/d33910dex991.htm'

df = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=[0])[0]
print (df.head())
```

This is my code and I want to extract all data from this website, but the result always be the first 'body'

```
0   1   2           3   4
0                           NaN NaN NaN         NaN NaN
1  Collection Period Beginning: NaN NaN  08/01/2020 NaN
2     Collection Period Ending: NaN NaN  08/31/2020 NaN
3  Previous Payment/Close Date: NaN NaN  08/17/2020 NaN
4                  Payment Date NaN NaN  09/15/2020 NaN
```

How can I get the rest of all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.read_html` returns a list of all the tables. You are just reading the initial table so it is giving you a single df.

try :

```
df = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=[0])
df1 = df[0]
df2 = df[1]
```

.. and so on to read all the df at the index. df holds the list and you can access the list elements at each index.